# Drupal 6 - How can I disable comments on all nodes / content_types?

Tags: drupal-6

How can I disable comments on all already existing nodes and disable comments by default for all content_types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run the following SQL query to disable comments on all existing nodes:

   ```
   UPDATE node SET comment=0  WHERE 1;
   ```
2. Go to `/admin/content/types` -> Edit each content_type -> Disable comments by default